# MFC use C# controlLibrary, crash in DDX_ManagedControl (CLR)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, mfc, clr

I am trying to use windows forms (C#) in the MFC C++ and [follow these step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/1te0bbs8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I have succeeded in this.

But, I make this project be a MFCDlg.dll
and put the MFCDlg.dll and WindowsControlLibrary1.dll (C#) in other project.

when i run the application it crashes at:

```
/*virtual*/void CXSScheduleUIDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_ManagedControl(pDX, IDC_SCHEDULE_GANTT, m_ctrlGantt);   Here
}
```

And show this error:

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in mfcDlg.dll*

What can be causing this?

Comment: when i try to use this function. it'S work!
    AfxEnableControlContainer();